# SciPy and App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, scipy

As far as I understand it `scipy` can't be used with GAE as the former uses C code. Is there a workaround for it? If not, can you recommend a package similar to `scipy` that I could use on GAE? Specifically, I'm trying to use the `brentq` method from `scipy.optimize`.

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This limitation can be avoided by using the [Python runtime in the App Engine flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/). However, depending on your expected loads, it might be significantly different in pricing than what you were expecting on a standard environment service, which has a free tier.

If costs are an issue, you might be able to use one of the Compute Engine microinstances to take advantage of the [always free tier for GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing#freeusage). You wouldn't get the scaling of App Engine, but that might not be an issue for your work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GAE Flexible by building custom runtime for C as it has been explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build). As it has mentioned:

> A custom runtime allows you to easily deploy and run web applications written in any language.